# VS Code can not reach Symfony\Component and Symfony\Bundle

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to create a simple symfony project.

I run this on console:

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton myProjectName 
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t myProjectName/public
```

Project succesfully run at localhost:8000. However, when I begin to inspect the code, I realized `VS Code` editor is indicating "Undefined type" error in `projectDirectory/src/Kernel.php` file. Do you have any ideas why this happens and any suggestions towards solution?

I use `PHP v7.4.32` and `Symfony 5.4` for development. My helper extentions are `PHP Intelephense v1.8.2` and `PHP IntelliSense v1.0.11`.

**projectDirectory/src/Kernel.php**

[image]

**The Error**

[image]

Comment: The [Symfony CLI](https://symfony.com/download) is the recommended way to create Symfony projects and it includes a nice debug server.  However, your composer create-project should still work and it should definitely populate the vendor/symfony directory.  I'd suggest trying it again and watch carefully for errors.  Make sure your composer is up to date as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since it runs succesfully on browser, I dubted that the classes exist somewhere but the VSCode could not solve the relative paths. Then, I tried a couple of extensions. Installation of `PHP` v1.22.11089 created by `DEVSENSE` and `PHP Namespace Resolver` v1.1.9 created by `Mehedi Hassan` has solved the problem.